# unable to add screenshot reportng selenium after escaping is set to false

Tags: selenium, testng, reportng

I am unable to add screenshot to reportNG html report. The output is coming as text like below

[a href="C:/2016.12.01.23.03.59.jpg"] [img src="C:/2016.12.01.23.03.59.jpg"/] [/a]

1.ReportNG reports are generating properly
2. I have set the escape property as  System.setProperty("org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output", "false")
3. I disabled the default listeners from project properties.
4. I added reportng listeners to testng.xml and pom.xml.

Not sure why the screenshots are not getting displayed. Please anyone suggest.

Comment: Can someone please help me on this context.

Comment: I am using these testng-6.7, selenium 2.52.0,reportng 1.1.4,guice 3.0, velocity 1.4 with maven

Comment: Can someone please throw some light on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem. In testng 6.7 version I could not find Reporter.setEscapeHTML method, which is why all the html tags are escaped. Now I changed to 6.8 version and set the Reporter.setEscapeHtml to false.It is working as expected.

Hope this would help someone who might have missed this property.

Thanks
Karthik